# How to create dependent JS drop down list by adding new specified options?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, frontend

I've created two select tags as "Material Group" which You can find in the link below:
[https://codepen.io/adan96/pen/ExaRgOe?editors=1010][1]

Considering single text values in both select tags named "Material Group" I want to select the first option in Product Hierarchy. E.g:

Material Group:
"001 - SWAC" and "001 - SRAY"
First select in Product Hierachy should have options:
"ASH-09BIR" and "ASH-12BIR"

Please check some JS code:

```
var select1 = document.getElementById("select1");
var select2 = document.getElementById("select2");
var select3 = document.getElementById("select3");
var select4 = document.getElementById("select4");
var select5 = document.getElementById("select5");

var productHierarchy = ["ASH-09BIR", "ASH-12BIR"];

if (select1.options[select1.selectedIndex].text == "001 - SWAC" && select2.options[select2.selectedIndex].text == "001 - SRAY") {
  for (var i = 0; i <= productHierarchy.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement("option");
    opt.value = opt.text = productHierarchy[i];
    console.log(opt.value);
    select3.add(opt);
  }
}
```

I've also tried "select3.appendChild(opt)". However, it still does not work, I cannot display these two new options from an array declared.

Could You please advice? ;)

Comment: I would recommend you have "Please select" options or the user cannot trigger the change. Also I STRONGLY recommend to EITHER use jQuery OR DOM manipulation.

Comment: The adding of options works fine, yet you do trigger that code on loading the script and not on changing the options of the related selects.

Answer (score 1):

First get all the select elements like,

```
const selects = document.querySelectorAll('select')
```

Then do `forEach` on all select box then make a separate `addEventListener` on each select like,

```
 selects.forEach(select => {
    select.addEventListener('change', () => {
      //Your logic here...
    })
 })
```

Then change `for (var i = 0; i <= productHierarchy.length; i++)`  **to** `for (var i = 0; i < productHierarchy.length; i++)` .. Only give (`<` and not `<=`) as only two elements are there in `productHierarchy`..

[**Forked Codepen example here...**](https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/JjdYEzm)

Comment: @adan96ful, Please accept the answer if it helps you by clicking on the tick below vote option in the answer..